# Is a disappearer original to Breaking Bad?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

I am not asking if such people really exist although there are certainly people who will provide false documents -- I am asking if this profession was invented by the writers of Breaking Bad (which of course would not be true if indeed it is a real profession) or occurred in other works of fiction.

The book The Getaway has the town of El Rey (also mentioned in From Dusk 'til Dawn) which is a place where criminals are given refuge for a price which guarantees eventual starvation.

And in real life, there is witness protection which is actually quite close to what the "disappearer" provides, but the difference is that the disappearer is freelance and is actually providing an illegal service.

Answer (score 3):

Browsing the dreaded site for the trope [master forger](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MasterForger), I found in the entry description for 'Escape to Victory' (1981)

> he goes to a fellow POW identified only as "The Forger". He not only
> has made his own camera to take pictures for the documents, but he's
> also gotten samples for all kinds of official documents

I didn't see this movie, (nor Breaking Bad), so I can't guarantee that it matches, but I'm pretty sure the trope of the 'technically evil' paper forger goes way earlier than Breaking Bad.

On the same page, the entry for 'Allo-Allo' (1980) states:

> Monsieur Roger LeClerc is a professional forger who provides whatever
> papers, passports and anything else the resistance need to implement
> whichever Zany Scheme they are trying this episode.

And made me think of the French Resistance in France (check [Adolfo Kaminsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolfo_Kaminsky)), in 1940ish. That in turn made me think of the [Underground Railroad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_Railroad).
While today both the resistance and the Underground Railroads are seen as heroes, they were outlaws in their own time.
So it matches the definitions of freelancers providing illegal services.